# Updating SQL field to delete empty line

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a SQL table like this :

```
TABLE "Books"
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Title" TEXT,
    "Description"   TEXT,
    "Price" TEXT
```

In the field description the content is always starting by 2 empty lines and finish by one empty line

Example :

```
"

My content is there
again here
maybe there

"
```

How could I update all my Table in once and delete the empty lines at the beginning and the end ?

Example of result:

```
"My content is there
again here
maybe there"
```

Comment: Are the double quotes included in the Description?

Comment: i think that's carriage return

Comment: @forpas No, that's just to show my text

Comment: @maSTAShuFu the duplicate link has nothing to do with this requirement. The OP does not want to remove all carriage returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim carriage returns and line feeds form both sides:

```
UPDATE Books
SET Description = TRIM(TRIM(Description, CHAR(13)), CHAR(10))
```

Maybe after that you need additional trimming of spaces, if they exist.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3744f4182f065e51fe5d2c328f7eed91).